# Oracle - Date substraction in where clause

Tags: oracle, date, date-arithmetic, operation

I'm trying to figure out how to compare the result of a date substraction in a where clause.

Clients subscribed to a service and therefore are linked to a subscription that has an end date. I want to display the list of subscriptions that will come to an end within the next 2 weeks.
I did not designed the databse but noticed that the End_Date column type is a varchar and not a date.. I can't change that.

My problem is the following:
If I try to select the result of the substraction for example with this request:

```
SELECT(TO_DATE(s.end_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') - TRUNC(SYSDATE)) , s.name  
from SUBSCRIPTION s WHERE s.id_acces = 15
```

This will work and give me the number of days between the end of the subscription and the current date.

BUT now, if I try to include the exact same request in a clause where for comparison:

```
SELECT s.name 
from SUBSCRIPTION S 
WHERE (TO_DATE(s.end_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') - TRUNC(SYSDATE))  between 0 and 16
```

I will get an error: "ORA-01839 : date not valid for month specified".
Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> " the End_Date column type is a varchar and not a date.. I can't
>   change that."

If you can't change the date you'll have to chang3 the data.  You can identify the rogue values with this function:

```
create or replace check_date_format (p_str in varchar2) return varchar2
is
   d date;
begin
   d := to_date(p_str,'YYYY-MM-DD');
   return 'VALID';
exception
   when others then
     return 'INVALID';
end;
```

You can use this function in a query:

```
select sid, end_date
from SUBSCRIPTION 
where check_date_format(end_date) != 'VALID';
```

Your choices are:

1. fix the data so all the dates are in the same format
2. fix the data and apply a check constraint to enforce future validity
3. write a bespoke MY_TO_DATE() function which takes a string and applies lots of different date format masks to it in the hope of getting a successful conversion.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere in the table you have your date formatted in a different way from `YYYY-MM-DD`. In your first query you check a certain row (or a set of rows, `s.id_acces = 15`), which is probably ok, but in the second you scan through all the table.

Try finding these rows with something like,

```
select end_date from subscription 
 where not regexp_like(end_date, '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}')
```

Comment: Damn thanks a lot ! Fortunately I had only 150 rows in the database. The problem came from the fact that there was a 2013-09-31 date in the data. Since 31st of september doesn't exist, that's why my request would not pass.

Answer (score 2):

Check your DD value (ie: day of the month). This value must be between 1 and the number of days in the month.

```
January - 1 to 31
February - 1 to 28 (1 to 29, if a leap year)
March - 1 to 31
April - 1 to 30
May - 1 to 31
June - 1 to 30
July - 1 to 31
August - 1 to 31
September - 1 to 30
October - 1 to 31
November - 1 to 30
December - 1 to 31
```